# Gzip compression for client/server over GRPC

Tags: go, compression, grpc, deprecated

I am trying to pin down a functional not deprecated not experimental solution to compressing payloads over GRPC. It seems updated documentation of this is hard to come by. Can anyone point me to something that works.

I believe that I need to use

```
"google.golang.org/grpc/encoding"
"google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/gzip"
```

On my client I am doing:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(":10000", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()), grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.UseCompressor("gzip")))
```

and on my server I am doing

```
serverOpts := []grpc.ServerOption{
    grpc.RPCCompressor(grpc.NewGZIPCompressor()),
    grpc.RPCDecompressor(grpc.NewGZIPDecompressor()),
}
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(serverOpts...)
```

however all of `RPCCompressor`, `NewGZIPCompressor`, `RPCDecompressor`, `NewGZIPDecompressor` are deprecated
and on the client I get

`grpc: Compressor is not installed for requested grpc-encoding "gzip"`
when I attempt to use it.

I attempted to init with

```
func init() {
    encoding.RegisterCompressor(&gzip.Compressor{})
}
```

however `Compressor` is undefined on gzip.
At this point I am going round in circles with whats available on Google from my searches. Anyone solved this?
I'm using `google.golang.org/grpc v1.54.0`

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you don't have to call `encoding.RegisterCompressor(&gzip.Compressor{})` because [it is available](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/encoding/gzip/gzip.go#L46) in the `init()` method of `google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/gzip` package. So you just have to import the `google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/gzip` package and there is no deprecated thing about it.

On the client side, [as the doc says](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/dialoptions.go#L210), `grpc.WithCompressor()` is deprecated and you can use `grpc.UseCompressor` as a call option:

```
// WithCompressor returns a DialOption which sets a Compressor to use for
// message compression. It has lower priority than the compressor set by the
// UseCompressor CallOption.
//
// Deprecated: use UseCompressor instead.  Will be supported throughout 1.x.
```

You can use it on your invokers like:

```
c, err := grpc.Dial(":9090")
// handle error here
err = c.Invoke(context.TODO(), "/mymethod", myArgs, myReply, grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name))
```

and there is no deprecated thing about it too.